# NG2 cable in Angular with Rails action cable is not configure(broadcast) on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, actioncable

I am working on Rails 5 action cable with angular 4 in the frontend.

I have got following error in console.

```
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://ec2-xxx-yyy-53-1ss.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing
```

I am confusing about the issue, is it related to Action Cable or NG Cable?

Please Help me.

Comment: it seems like server misconfiguration

Comment: can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111066/rails-5-2-app-with-angular-as-front-end-not-able-to-run-on-local-to-make-a-call.